# Add icon on top of featured image based on article tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a website with some  articles accessible only for Members. All articles, accessible or not are shown on a page and i would like to add an icon on top of the featured image for people to understand which articles they can see for free or not.

Could you help ? I've already read the doc about featured image but my brain can't make the whole thing...

Here's what i already tried :

```
function article_reserve( $title ) {
    if ( has_tag( 'abonne' ) ) {
        $title = 'test ' . $title;
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'article_reserve' );
```

It change the title but i'm trying to change the featured image

Also tried that after comments :

```
function wpse_post_thumbnail_html( $html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr ) {
    // Optionally add any logic here for determining what markup to output.
    // $html will be an empty string if there is no post thumbnail.
    if ( has_tag( 'abonne' ) ) {
    $new_html = '<img src="https://placekitten.com/g/600/600" alt="kitten">';
    }
    return $new_html;
}
add_action( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'wpse_post_thumbnail_html', 10, 5 );
```

Comment: Are you trying to switch out the image for a different one, or are you just trying to add an icon over the existing one? The former would definitively be a case for the `post_thumbnail_html` hook (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/252785), the latter might rather be an issue to handle in the respective template. (Although, since the filter is supposed to return HTML code for the image, it could probably be amended with a container element plus code for the icon in that place as well.)

Comment: Thanks for you reply ! I'm trying to add an icon on top of an existing image :) Tried your solution but i think i messed up lol